My whole scene is purple image
I was working on a project for a month, so I saved every blend file, about 35 files in one scene.
I was working on a file and suddenly when I tried to render it, the whole scene is literally just purple image.
The view port is normal I can see the whole scene , but only in render cycles , its just purple, I checked HDRI its just there I tried changing the HDRI to sky texture, still the same issue.
What is the issue?





Do you have something inside the video sequencer editor ? Is the option Output > Post Processing > Sequencer disabled ?

maybe in the Outliner make invisible for render all the objects that you've made invisible for preview?

3 years of experience in blender and we still make simple mistakes :) lol thank you lutzi , it was in the video sequencer didnt notice at all

moonboots thank you , it all worked actually , cheers guys
